# Can I put formatted HTML code as Javascript alert() input parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I have this simpe Javascript script that show a popup box when a link is clicked:

```
    <script>
        function myExample() {
            alert("BaZing!  It works!");
        }
    </script>
```

I want to know if it is possible to format the text inside the alert() function.

In particular I want to know if (and how) is it possible to put some formatted HTML text as alert() input parameter.

Some one can help me?

Comment: As long as it's a string, you can put anything you'd like in there? HTML and styles doesn't work on OS/browser specific windows, obviously!

Comment: You can't, use a custom modal.

Answer (score 3):

No, `alert()` [accepts one string argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert) and will display it as is.

If you need to display a formatted text in a modal, use a library (e.g. [Alertify.js](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/)).

Answer (score 1):

alert() can't format a HTML format string, but if you just want separate a string to several lines, you can put '\n' in your string,like

alert("first line \n second line \n third line");